# Looking for a filter to modify the months

Tags: plugins, filters, date

Hi making a simple plugin that replaces the wrong russian month with the right ones.
But I can't find any filters that works.

I have tried these filters without success:

> add_filter('get_the_modified_date', 'russian-month');
>   add_filter('the_modified_date', 'russian-month');
>   add_filter('date_rewrite_rules', 'russian-month');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `add_filter('the_time', 'your_function');` or `add_filter('the_date', 'your_function');` depending on which function you use in your theme.